# Creating a generic table in view from an action (button)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am relatively new to MVC and its kicking my butt!

I have a view that has an empty dataTable on it. There are a few drop downs that determine the actions that will occur.

Drop down 1 - Selects from a list of databases
Drop down 2 - Populated via JSON with the tables in the db selected (From Drop down 1)
then a button. OnClick it fires and grabs all the data from the database.

Originally it was a single table, so i was able to use a model and a partial view. But now that I have possibly thousands of table schemas to consider, I have no clue how to set it up. I grabbed the data from the database and pushed it to a public data table in my controller. From there i tried getting it to display to the view, but the only thought i had was push it to the viewbag. But doing so never calls anything when it returns back to the view.

please assist if you can.

Thanks in advance
Samantha

```
    `
    $(function() {
    $('#Btnfilter').click(function () {
        var table = $('#search_result');
        var dataObject = document.getElementById('drpdatabase').value + "," + document.getElementById('tableList').value + "," + document.getElementById('returnlist').value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTable","Transaction")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { dataObject : dataObject },
            context: table,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                //table.DataTable( {
                //    data: data
                //} );               
            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log("fail " + data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

`

Comment: are you using dataTables.net? do you want a dynamic table that will display the database table depending on the table database and table selected?

Comment: yes I am. Intention is to use two drop downs. First one selects the database user has permissions to, second one is tables they can access in that db. On click of that, fires a ajax request to return a table. in my controller its returning a dataTable but when i step back to my view it only hits fail for the JSON
return Json((DataTable) data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Can you post the Json you are getting from the server?

Comment: Actually I was able to get it to finally work a few days ago. It was a ambiguous java script reference causing the disconnect. Thank you all though